# Update Cookie to remove an element C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am creating an internal site for my company, my landing page consists of tiles that are a mix of required and optional tiles. The list of tiles and their respective order are save in a cookie as a JSON string. I build the cookie just fine, i can update it whenever the order changes without a problem. I issue is when i have them click on the remove button on the optional tile. It will not remove it from the cookie.

Here is the code in the partial for the ajax request:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "RemoveTile", "Home", new { id = "_EventsTile" }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess= "$(this).closest('.tilePartial').remove(); location.reload();" }, new { @class = "fas fa-clickable fa-window-close removeTile", @style = "color:red; font-size:1.5em; padding-top:1%" })
```

Here is the code of the action in the controller:

```
private void UpdateCookie(object obj, string cookieName, int expiredays = 30)
        {

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            cookie.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiredays);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        public void RemoveTile(string id)
        {
            List<TileInfo> newCookie = new List<TileInfo>();
            var cookieInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TileInfo>>(Request.Cookies["TilePreferences"].Value);

            var removed = cookieInfo.FirstOrDefault(f => f.PartialName == id);
            cookieInfo.Remove(removed);
            //newCookie = cookieInfo;
            UpdateCookie(cookieInfo, "TilePreferences", 90);

            Response.StatusCode = 200;

        }
```

and the default value and what is is "supposed" to look like when it is done:

Before:

```
[
    {"PartialName":"_BulletinBoardTile","TileOrder":0},
    {"PartialName":"_TimeCardTile","TileOrder":1},
    {"PartialName":"_FeedbackTile","TileOrder":2},
    {"PartialName":"_CouncilTile","TileOrder":3},
    {"PartialName":"_EventsTile","TileOrder":4}
]
```

After(intention):

```
[
    {"PartialName":"_BulletinBoardTile","TileOrder":0},
    {"PartialName":"_TimeCardTile","TileOrder":1},
    {"PartialName":"_FeedbackTile","TileOrder":2},
    {"PartialName":"_CouncilTile","TileOrder":3}
}
```

any help is appreciated.

This code for updating the order in the file works with no issues:

```
public void UpdateTileOrder(string jsonString)
        {
            List<string> TileList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonString);
            var cookieInfo = new List<TileInfo>();
            var i = 0;

            foreach (var item in TileList)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                {
                    var tile = new TileInfo
                    {
                        PartialName = item,
                        TileOrder = i
                    };
                    cookieInfo.Add(tile);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            UpdateCookie(cookieInfo, "TilePreferences", 90);
        }
```

Comment: Your link passes externalEvents. The json is called eventstile

Comment: I replaced that and it still will not update.

Comment: I would add a `if (removed == null) { Response.StatusCode = 404; return}` to your method.  That way you can see if your FirstOrDefault is failing